# Azure functions CLI latest templates

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I'd like to create a new Azure Function that makes use of a template for OpenApi support as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/openapi-apim-integrate-visual-studio#create-a-functions-project)

Since I'm using a Mac rather than Windows, I'd like to know how I can make the latest templates available from the CLI or VS Code.

I tried

```
func new --template "Http Trigger with OpenAPI" --name MyHttpTrigger
```

But that gave

```
Unknown template 'HttpTriggerwithOpenAPI' (Parameter 'templateName')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK,
Before Creating the Azure Function with the cmdlet `func new ...`, check if the required template is available in the language (stack) you're going to create it.

1. `func templates list` - Run this cmdlet to see what templates available according to specific language runtime (C#, JavaScript) you are creating.

[image]

If the template is available, you can create that on the Azure Functions Project using the `func new` cmdlet.

Refer to the [`func new`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-core-tools-reference?tabs=v2#func-new) cmdlet MS Doc for more information.